# FreeRadius not starting

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, freeradius

My FreeRadius server has gone south.  Not sure what happened (or even what changed), but it now will not start as a service at boot or from CLI.  The database is MariaDB.  Journalctl -xe shows:

```
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.19
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: Copyright (C) 1999-2019 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: PARTICULAR PURPOSE
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: GNU General Public License
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: Starting - reading configuration files ...
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: Debugger not attached
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_sql (sql): Driver rlm_sql_mysql (module rlm_sql_mysql) loaded and linked
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: Creating attribute SQL-Group
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: Creating attribute Unix-Group
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_sql_mysql: libmysql version: 8.0.20
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect to database "radius"
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_sql (sql): Initialising connection pool
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_sql (sql): Processing generate_sql_clients
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_sql (sql) in generate_sql_clients: query is SELECT id, nasname, shortname, type, secret, server FROM nas
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_sql (sql): 0 of 0 connections in use.  You  may need to increase "spare"
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_sql (sql): Opening additional connection (0), 1 of 1 pending slots used
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection (0)
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_sql (sql): Released connection (0)
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_detail (auth_log): 'User-Password' suppressed, will not appear in detail output
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_mschap (mschap): using internal authentication
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: tls: Using cached TLS configuration from previous invocation
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_cache (cache_eap): Driver rlm_cache_rbtree (module rlm_cache_rbtree) loaded and linked
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: Ignoring "ldap" (see raddb/mods-available/README.rst)
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: radiusd: #### Skipping IP addresses and Ports ####
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: Configuration appears to be OK
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_sql (sql): Removing connection pool
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v freeradius[26433]: rlm_sql (sql): Closing connection (0)
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v kernel: freeradius[26433]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f182787423f sp 00007ffeb337bbf0 error 4 in libmysqlclient.so.21.1.20[7f1827812000+e7000]
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v kernel: Code: 48 89 e5 41 54 53 48 8d 1d 3e 45 66 00 4c 8d a3 00 40 00 00 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 48 8b 3b 48 85 ff 74 12 48 8b 87 c0 00 00 00 <48> 8b 40 08 48 85 c0 74 
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Control process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
```

Running freeradius -C -lstdout -xxx returns a few warnings about things that aren't being used, but indicates the "Configuration appears to be OK".  Freeradius DOES run from a CLI when executed as either freeradius -X or freeradius -f -lstdout from root.

Any suggestions as to where to look to get this going again?

Comment: Not sure why the question was downvoted, just downvoting without feedback doesn't help much.  Either way, was able to resolve, will add more as the comments don't appear to be the right place for this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue, but it took a rebuild and I believe there is an issue with how FreeRadius is connecting to MariaDB through the libmysqlclient.so.

I rebuilt a new server using my written build directions from before.  After connecting sql into the mods-enabled directory and starting FreeRadius, same error was thrown.  I looked everything over and rebuilt using MySQL and no errors.  I then copied the original FreeRadius directory over, and - after starting - again, no errors.

I know MariaDB and MySQL are supposed to be compatible, but it appears an update has broken that compatibility (at least for my use).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the freeradius.service file, not sure if the user/group actually helps but commenting ExecStartPre line definitely did the trick.

```
[Service]
User=freerad
Group=freerad
Type=notify
PIDFile=/run/freeradius/freeradius.pid
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/freeradius
#ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/freeradius $FREERADIUS_OPTIONS -Cxm -lstdout
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/freeradius -f $FREERADIUS_OPTIONS
#Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

```
May 11 00:13:37 znt-ntm-002v kernel: freeradius[26433]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f182787423f sp 00007ffeb337bbf0 error 4 in libmysqlclient.so.21.1.20[7f1827812000+e7000]
```

From the lint, it's clear something is wrong with MySQL, you should try to check if the MySQL server is still available.

Maybe you can just comment out the MySQL module for freeradius, it uses the file as a database in default, in that way it should start.